# Enter keyboard input in Windows Form (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, calculator, keyboard-events

I made a calculator and the only thing left to do is to make it work from keyboard input. It all works perfect untill I get to the Enter KeyDown. The problem is that when I start my calculator, a topleft button is selected and if I press Enter it will instead call the method of that specific button (number 7). It also appears that if I click any button at all, it will be selected, and same thing would happen if I press Enter.

I tried to set my form to acceptButton = "none" and to "equal_btn" (my equal button, I want to use it when I press Enter), but it didn't help

```cs
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.D0:
                    btn_zero.PerformClick();
                    /*PerformClick() because all methods are for buttons*/
                    break;
                case Keys.D1:
                    btn_one.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case Keys.D2:
                    btn_two.PerformClick();
                    break;
                /*......*/
                case Keys.Oemplus:
                    plus.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case Keys.Enter:
                    equal.PerformClick();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

What I expect is to when I press Enter, the button Equal method will be called. Instead as said before it calles only sellected buttons.
Btw all other buttons work perfectly.

(hope I didn't miss anything on StackOverflow, otherwise sorry)

Comment: First up, set your tab order so your calculator's text box that has the digits in is first in the tab order, then put an event handler on every button's GotFocus event, and make it so the handler transfers the focus back to the textbox

Comment: Excuse me but how do I change tab order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is in the `Form1_Load` change the focus to other element, for example, the equals wich will be your enter i assume. where you have the calculator.
like `btnEnter.Select();` what will prevent to run that method in the button.

finally to change the tab order as **Cais Jard** said you have two options, one is in the file `Form1.designer.cs` and in the initialize components you have all the buttons etc. then there youhave them listed like this `this.buttonXX.TabIndex = 0;` just change for the one you want.

The other option to change the `tabindex` is in the properties of the element. which basically, go to the designer, click over the element and press `F4` inside the submenu `behavior` you have the option `tabindex`

Comment: It works at start, but when i click any other button using mouse it selects that button and then it's all broken again. Maybe I didn't understand you with tabindex, I'am not really sure what does this do. I have all buttons now at tabindex at zero though.

Comment: your issue is that there is a preselected button no? just try to change that preselected button by default. thats what `tabindex=0` does

Comment: I am sorry that I'm unclear. The preselected button worked, Equal_btn is selecten when I started the program. The problem is when i start to use my mouse instead. When i click any button (we say 7) then it will be selected and when I press with my keyboard Enter, it will call the selected buttons methid (in other words it will print out 7)

Comment: Well I fixed it by calling equal_btn.Select(); after every button method. Thank ypu very much!

Comment: @Alex_Joo you're not supposed to set tabindex=0 for everything. youre supposed to set it to an incrementing index based on the order youd want the TAB key to move between the buttons if pressed repeatedly. for an easy way to see it open the designer, go VIEW menu, TAB ORDER to see the current order. To change it click everything in order. if you make a mistake, you have to start over (VIEW>>TAB ORDER to switch it off, VIEW>>TAB ORDER to switch tab order mode on again)

Comment: Video tut: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=107&v=_5nYAwOUe1I  - tab order does NOT change the focus behavior of your app, it just sets the order that controls are activated when you tab tab tab (you see the highlight move from button to button).. The control with the lowest tab index is the one that is focused by default when the form opens